# Ideapad 330-15IKB Ubuntu 18.04 overheat and battery problems

Tags: nvidia, lenovo, battery, overheating, ideapad

we have about 50 ideapad 330-15IKB with ubuntu 18.04 lts installed ... we face multiproblems :

1- overheat a lot even if nothing working on it

2- battery drops quickly caused of overheat

3- system freeze sometimes

4- system freeze at reboot or shutdown

5- wifi adapter disapeared sometimes or disconnect whil working

i've tried to reinstall ubuntu, disable nvidia vga , update to kernel 5.2 ... but issues still there !

is there any solution for these problems

Comment: Did you find anything else on this? I bought this laptop with Windows 10 and it displays the same problems listed above. I was considering migrating to Ubuntu or Lubuntu, but apparently the problems persist

Comment: no .... not solved ...

Comment: but it works fine on windows 10 though

Comment: tks. I ended up installing Lubuntu 18.04 on it and has been working fine (not to mention crazy fast)